# Multiple highlights in a menu

Tags: android

I have a menu I am using for my navigation drawer. The menu has separate sub-menus- and I want each sub-menu to have its own highlight when a item is clicked- but when I click a item in either one of my sub-menus the highlight on the other sub-menu is cleared. Is there a behavior or a way to make it so my highlights on one sub-menu are not affected by that of the other? here is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/op1"
        android:title="Option 1" />
</group>

<item android:id="@+id/op2"
    android:title="Option 2" >
    <menu>
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/op2sub1"
            android:title="SubOption 1" />
        <item android:id="@+id/op2sub2"
            android:title="SubOption 2" />
</group>
    </menu>
</item>

</menu>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using this menu for navigation? If so, the highlighting is supposed to show which part of the app you're viewing, and having two highlighted regions could be confusing.

Comment: @TheoKanning No its used to filtering

Answer (score 0):

You could get a reference to the menu as a `ListView`, call `setChoiceMode(CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)`, and then listen to clicks yourself.

```
listView.setChoiceMode(CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemCLickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(isChecked(position)){
            listView.setItemChecked(position, false);
            //Your other code here
        else {
            listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
            //Your other code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a navigation view

Comment: Looks like I was looking at outdated Android documentation, surprise surprise... The current `NavigationView` will only allow one to be selected at a time, but you could manually change the background color of selected rows instead